# Is it possible to set an action view to a NavigationView sub header(label) item?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I am using the NavigationView to implement my navigation drawer and the items I am displaying in it are dynamic, so I am building it programmatically in java code, not in xml menu.
[This is what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCUfn.png)

But for now I could only implement [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UEgS.png)

Does anyone have any idea how can I achieve that using the NavigationView component without writing my custom drawer with a RecyclerView/ListView, third party libraries are an option only if they use the NavigationView class?

Comment: Forgot to mention in the question description, the problem is that I can't set an actionView to the Sub header(label) item.

Comment: Please post the code inside menu xml which you've used for Navigationview.

Comment: Did you try to get with navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.subHeaderId) ?